# Draggable image slider

Tags: php, jquery, animation, web-deployment, banner

I'm relatively new to the world of programming and this is my first question on stack overflow. I have to create a system written in php and jquery that allows  to order a series of images and, based on the order,  create a banner-style animation. The only problem is that when the script selects the images from the div to create the animation they disappear. thanks in advance for your collaboration

*the javascript*

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    const images = document.querySelectorAll('.imgw');
    $('#preview').html(images[0]);
    $("#genera").click(function () {
        setInterval(banner, 2500);
        var index = 1;
    });
});

const banner = () => $('#preview').fadeOut('slow', function () {
    $(this).html(images[index]);
    $(this).fadeIn('slow', function () {
        if (index == images.length - 1) {
            index = 0;
        } else {
            index++;
        }
    });
})
```

*the html file*

```
<section>
    <div class="row" style="margin-top:25px;">
        <div class="col text-center">
            <h2 style="margin-top:25px;">Anteprima</h2>
            <div id="preview">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>

<section>
    <div class="row" id="slides" style="margin-top:25px;">
        <div class="col text-center">
            <!-- <div id="box"> -->
            <h2 style="margin-top:25px;">Slides</h2>
            <ul id="sortable">

                <?php
                $html = "";
                $count = 1;
                foreach ($images as $img) {
                    $url = $img["url"];
                    $size = $img["size"];
                    $humanSize = $img["human_size"];
                    $html .= "\t\t<img src='{$url}' class='imgw' id='{$count}'  alt='image_{$count}' />\n";
                    $count++;
                }
                echo $html;
                ?>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

Comment: first you pick `images[0]` and place it into the preview. then you fade it out, set a new image inside and fade that in again. where in this process is the code not behaving as expected?

Comment: Selecting the images with `` const images = document.querySelectorAll ('. imgw');
`` when i go to show them in the animation (div preview) they disappear from the div slides, i would like the images to remain in that div

Answer (score 0):

I read the documentation better and solved the problem

*the javascript*

```
var images = $('.ui-sortable').children("img").clone();
    var index = 1;
    const banner = () => $('#anteprima').fadeOut('slow', function () {
        $(this).html(images[index]);
        $(this).fadeIn('slow', function () {
            if (index == images.length - 1) {
                index = 0;
            } else {
                index++;
            }
        });
    })
    setInterval(banner, 2500);
```